# Laravel 5.3: How to use Auth in Service Provider?

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-5.3

I am passing a value in shared view by taking value from table. I need to know user ID for the purpose but `Auth::check()` returns false. How do I do it? Below is code:

```
public function boot()
    {
        $basket_count = 0;
        if (Auth::check()) { //always false
            $loggedin_user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $basket_count = Cart::getBasketCount();
        }
        view()->share('basket_count', $basket_count);
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to use Laravel's `Event Listener`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events

Comment: Try something like this `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`
`public function boot($guard = null)`
`$auth = Auth::guard($guard);`
`$auth->guest() true or false`
`$auth->user()`

Comment: @Froxz `guest` is true

Comment: Are you sure you are logged in?

Comment: offcourse I am.

Comment: @Froxz I sorted it out, Check answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK turns out that `ServiceProviders` are not place for such things. The best thing is a `Middleware`. So if you want to call Auth, create middleware and pass value to views.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {            
        $basket_count = 0;
        if ($this->auth) { //always false
            $loggedin_user_id = $this->auth->user()->id;
            $basket_count = Cart::getBasketCount($loggedin_user_id);
        }
        view()->share('basket_count', $basket_count);

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use authentication directly in the controller file. Adding it in the middleware is a cleaner way of doing the authentication.

For eg. In CategoriesController.php

...

> class CategoryController extends Controller {
>
> ```
> /**
>  * CategoryController constructor.
>  */
> public function __construct()
> {
>     $this->middleware('auth');
> }
> ```

...

If you want to have a look at a complete example
http://deepdivetuts.com/basic-create-edit-update-delete-functionality-laravel-5-3