# Laravel 5.7 - Access Auth::User() inside a service provider

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to access to the current user in a service provider of a module. The `Auth::user()` returns null. I know the middleware is called after the service provider and that is why this is null. Is there any solution to this problem? it is my code

```
namespace Modules\User\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Nwidart\Modules\Facades\Module;

class ViewComposerProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
     *
     * @var bool
     */

    protected $defer = false;

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->buildMenu();
        $this->buildAvatar();
    }

    public function register()
    {
        dd(Auth::user());//null
    }

    private function buildAvatar(){
        $f = Auth::user();
        dd($f); // null
    }

    public function buildMenu()
    {
        view()->composer('layouts.subnavbar', function ($view) {
            $t = \Nwidart\Modules\Facades\Module::getByStatus(1);
            $modules = [];
            foreach ($t as $item)
                $modules[] = $item->name;
            $view->with('modules', $modules);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.3: How to use Auth in Service Provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588918/laravel-5-3-how-to-use-auth-in-service-provider)

Comment: You should be doing this in the middleware, not the service itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using auth in laravel service provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201459/using-auth-in-laravel-service-provider)

Comment: Hello. Guys I tried all of them. not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling the user in the provider you could make 2 view composers, 1 for the menu and 1 for the avatar

AvatarComposer.php

```
class AvatarComposer
{

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $avatar = Auth::user()->avatar//AVATAR HERE
        $view->with('avatar', $avatar);
    }
}
```

ModuleComposer.php

```
class ModuleComposer
{
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $t = \Nwidart\Modules\Facades\Module::getByStatus(1);
        $modules = [];
        foreach ($t as $item)
            $modules[] = $item->name;
        $view->with('modules', $modules);
    }
}
```

and then in the `boot` of your provider:

```
//make it public for all routes
View::composer('*', AvatarComposer::class);

View::composer('layouts.subnavbar', ModuleComposer::class);
```

Comment: The classes should extend `serviceprovider`?

Comment: No, you can check the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers

Comment: well, it is `class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider`

Comment: Ok, I try `class ProfileComposer`

Comment: The ServiceProvider where you write View::composer must inject the serviceprovider indeed

Comment: It works, thanks. But what difference does it make, to declare composer outside the provider?

Comment: The composer will be called after everything is imported including the auth, you can find the explanation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/providers#the-boot-method