# Laravel Auth::check() always return false in AppServiceProvider.php

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to executing a function in every page and I do that in `AppServiceProvider.php` in `boot()` I dependent on `Auth` class but `Auth::check()` always return `false`

```
 namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Auth;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

        dd(Auth::check());
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588918/laravel-5-3-how-to-use-auth-in-service-provider

Comment: Hy, i working with symfony (so I dont know deeply Laravel)... but... I think you need use inside App\Providers namespace:  App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
... you can use just like Auth inside namespace App\Http\Controllers;

Comment: Thanks guys I used middleware instead

Answer (score 1):

From the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/lifecycle)

> Service providers are truly the key to bootstrapping a Laravel application. The application instance is created, the service providers are registered, and the request is handed to the bootstrapped application. It's really that simple!
>
> Once the application has been bootstrapped and all service providers have been registered, the Request will be handed off to the router for dispatching. The router will dispatch the request to a route or controller, as well as run any route specific middleware.

and since Auth and Session are updated / initialized using a middleware, it means that you can't access to it from a Service Provider.

you can only bind data to views in your service providers using callbacks that are called when the view is rendered ( it means that the server is already preparing the response )

```php
View::composer('is_authenticated', Auth::check());
```

Comment: how I can achieve same when using APIs as their are not blade/view used when using Laravel API's

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Auth is not load on before AppServiceProvider. Because in Controllers Auth::check() work well. So i think using Auth::check() in AppServiceProvider is very bad idea. AppServiceProvider intended to register and bootstrap services, maybe there a better place for Auth::check() in you app?

Answer (score 0):

you need view composer for this.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Auth;
use DB;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('*', function ($view) 
        {
            if (Auth::check()) {

            }   
        });  
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To correctly protect a route for only authorised users, you should use `->middleware('auth')` on your route.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication

Also I would suggest updating your question to include the Laravel version you are using.